# What's the meaning of the Swapped Size in VM Tracker Instruments?

Tags: ios, memory-management

[VM Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHvEN.png)

As the picture show，what's the meaning of the Swapped Size in VM Tracker Instruments?
As far as I know，iOS system does't has the Swap function in VM,so the Swapped Size means what?
Thank you for telling me！